# Error deserializing message from kafka topic with ksqldb-server

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I am getting the following error message while running a query on a stream:

```
ERROR {"type":0,"deserializationError":{"target":"value","errorMessage":"Error deserializing message from topic: deployment","recordB64":"HnloOTgyaGl1cXN4aG85OVZnaXRodWIuY29tL21pbmR0aWNrbGUvY29udGVudC1zeW5jLXdvcmtmbG93KmNvbnRlbnQtc3luYy13b3JrZmxvdwZjbnQ=","cause":["Failed to deserialize data for topic deployment to Avro: ","Unknown magic byte!"],"topic":"deployment"},"recordProcessingError":null,"productionError":null,"serializationError":null,"kafkaStreamsThreadError":null} (processing.transient_DEPLOYMENT_603110738765559581.KsqlTopic.Source.deserializer)
ksql-server        | [2023-07-22 21:31:59,605] WARN stream-thread [_confluent-ksql-ksql-examples-service-idtransient_transient_DEPLOYMENT_603110738765559581_1690061516393-80259bf8-0a07-46fa-b86b-864a9a359fc7-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Skipping record due to deserialization error. topic=[deployment] partition=[1] offset=[29] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer)
```

I created the stream with the following:
`Create Stream deployment with (KAFKA_TOPIC='deployment', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY_FORMAT='AVRO', PARTITIONS=2, VALUE_SCHEMA_ID=1, KEY_SCHEMA_ID=1);`

The stream is getting created successfully.
My docker-compose file for starting the setup looks like:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2'
        hostname: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        networks:
            - ksql-poc
        ports:
            - '32181:32181'
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

    kafka:
        image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2'
        hostname: kafka
        container_name: kafka
        networks:
            - ksql-poc
        ports:
            - '9092:9092'
            - '29092:29092'
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
            KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
            KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

    schema-registry:
        image: 'confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.2'
        hostname: schema-registry
        container_name: schema-registry
        networks:
            - ksql-poc
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
            - kafka
        ports:
            - '8081:8081'
        environment:
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181

    # Runs the Kafka KSQL Server
    ksql-server:
        image: 'confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.3.2'
        hostname: ksql-server
        container_name: ksql-server
        networks:
            - ksql-poc
        ports:
            - '8088:8088'
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - schema-registry
        environment:
            KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: '/etc/ksql'
            KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
            KSQL_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8088'
            KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: 'ksql-examples-service-id'
            KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_NAME: 'ksql_processing_log'
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
            KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_ROWS_INCLUDE: 'true'
            # KSQL_LOG4J_OPTS: '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksql/log4j-rolling.properties'

    # Runs the KSQL CLI
    ksql-cli:
        image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.3.2
        container_name: ksql-cli
        hostname: ksql-cli
        networks:
            - ksql-poc
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - ksql-server
        entrypoint: /bin/sh
        tty: true

networks:
    ksql-poc:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
```

I have registered the schema with the following request:
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \ --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Deployment\",\"namespace\":\"com.onrush.domain.event.schema\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"repo\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"teamId\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}' \ http://localhost:8081/subjects/deployment-value/versions`

On running `print 'deployment';` I am getting the following result:

```
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2023/07/23 10:07:13.993 Z, key: <null>, value: yh982hiuqsxho99Vgithub.com/xyz/content-sync-workflow*content-sync-workflowcnt, partition: 0
rowtime: 2023/07/23 10:07:14.155 Z, key: <null>, value: yh982hiuqsxho99Vgithub.com/xyz/content-sync-workflow*content-sync-workflowcnt, partition: 1
rowtime: 2023/07/23 10:07:14.164 Z, key: <null>, value: yh982hiuqsxho99Vgithub.com/xyz/content-sync-workflow*content-sync-workflowcnt, partition: 1
```

Not sure if there is an issue with producing the message. If it's not in the right format, although i've used avro ecoder to convert the message as follows:

```
avroData := map[string]interface{}{
        "id":     "yh982hiuqsxho99",
        "repo":   "github.com/xyz/content-sync-workflow",
        "name":   "content-sync-workflow",
        "teamId": "cnt",
    }

binaryAvroData, err := codec.BinaryFromNative(nil, avroData)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error encoding Avro data:", err)
}

message := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
    Topic: topic,
    Value: sarama.ByteEncoder(binaryAvroData),
}
```

I am exploring ksql, so not i'm exactly able to find the issue here. With the same schema I am able to produce and consume messages from kafka with code in golang, but getting above error when trying with ksqldb-cli.

I am expecting the following query to run successully:
`select * from deployment;`
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but the schema registry should not be using both Zookeeper and Kafka connections and you only need port 9092 mapped for Kafka

Answer (score 0):

Your sarama producer isn't using the schema registry. Ksql Avro parser expects you to use it.

You'll need to fix your producer to correctly encode the Avro data, potentially using a different library. Most Kafka Avro serializers by Confluent automatically register a schema, so you shouldn't need to do that manually